# JQuery - setTimeout is not delayed

Tags: jquery

I've got a method which is doing something when a div is loaded.
My problem is error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My function is:

```
function checkIsDivLoaded(div) {
    if (div.is(':visible')) {
        //do something
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkIsDivLoaded(div), 2000);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the delay for 2 seconds, but when I will call this method I get the error above immediately so this delay isn't working.
I did another test like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { alert('test'); }, 2000);
});
```

and it's working fine, after 2 second this alert is showing.

I am a little bit confused why setTimeout isn't working in first case, but is working very well in the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the output of the function call and not giving a callback function. You need to write the syntax / code this way:

```js
function checkIsDivLoaded(div) {
    if (div.is(':visible')) {
        //do something
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            checkIsDivLoaded(div);
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

This is also one of the most common mistakes made with event handlers using callback functions.

In simple terms, the first parameter of `setTimeout()` should be a function. In the correctly working case, you have created an anonymous function. But where you said it's not working, you are sending the output of the result of `checkIsDivLoaded(div)`, which is **not a function**.

I hope this explanation clears it.